# Issue when adding to a list from a different script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to add items from one script to another. The lives on the player script as is trying to have items added from enemy script with a trigger enter.

Null Exception

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Enemy_Main.AddEnemyToConnectionList (UnityEngine.Collider2D enemy) (at Assets/Script/EnemyScript/Enemy_Main.cs:46)
Enemy_Main.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D other) (at Assets/Script/EnemyScript/Enemy_Main.cs:25)

Function on Player Script

```
    private void AddEnemyToConnectionList(Collider2D enemy) {
    pm.AddToProjectileList(enemy.gameObject);
}
```

}

Function on Enemy Script

```
   private void AddEnemyToConnectionList(Collider2D enemy) {
    pm.AddToProjectileList(enemy.gameObject);
```